# Usage of allergy

Tags: usage

What is the proper usage of allergy?

To start, I make some examples the way I know it and please help me verify. Thank you.

**Right now:** 
I am having an dog allergy.
I am having an dog allergy attack.

**Describing who I am:**
I have a dog allergy. 
I am allergic to dog. 
Dog is an allergy to me. (The last one sounds weird. This shouldn't be a common usage. )

**Describe what it is:**
Dog causes allergy.

**Wrong usage:**
Dog is allergic to me. 
Dog is allergic.

Answer (score 4):

**Right now**: I am having a dog allergy. I am having a dog allergy attack. (note: 'a' not 'an')

**Describing who I am:** I have a dog allergy. I am allergic to dogs. (note the plural dogs) You are right, the last one is weird.

**Describe what it is:** My allergy is caused by dogs. This allergy is caused by dogs.

**Wrong usage:** These expressions make it sound like the dog is experiencing discomfort caused by an allergy to you!

Comment: How about ***I am allergic to a dog*** or ***My allergy is caused by a dog*** instead of the plural form **dogs**? I am asking this, as OP just used **dog** without the article **a**. I will be grateful if you would give a reply. :)

Answer (score 2):

You "have an allergy". Since this is normally a long-term state (you have the allergy even when not suffering from it) you would not say "I am having an allergy."

You say "I have an allergy to dogs" (note the plural)

You can also use "allergic" as "I am allergic to dogs"

The result of a dog allergy can be sneezing, or even an asthma attack. If you were talking of "right now" you would say something like "My dog allergy is giving me a runny nose." It is more natural to describe the symptoms of the allergy than to say a "dog allergy attack"

You can describe what it is with the word "reaction": I get a reaction to dog-dander.

Of course, dogs can be allergic, they are often allergic to various foods, this causes the dog to suffer.

Comment: From the last sentence of your answer, would it be still correct and keep the same meaning to say **They can be often allergic to various foods** instead of **they are often allergic to various foods**?

Comment: I am sorry to ask you too much, but I'd like to ask one thing more: can the sentence **Dogs can be allergic** stand alone without adding the cause of the allergy? For instance, can I say ***This dog is allergic*** instead of ***This dog has a allergy***? It would be very thankful if you give me helps.